# Prisma missing arguments

Tags: javascript, nestjs, prisma

I my `schema.prisma` file I have those 2 models:

```
model User {
  id              String @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  firstName       String @map("first_name") @db.VarChar(40)
  lastName        String @map("last_name") @db.VarChar(40)
  email           String @unique @db.Citext
  phone           String @db.VarChar(60)
  dialCode        String @map("dial_code") @db.VarChar(5)
  password        String @db.VarChar(500)
  twoFactorSecret String @db.VarChar(300)
  roleId          String @map("role_id") @db.Uuid

  role              Role                   @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  customPermissions UserCustomPermission[]

  updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)

  @@unique([dialCode, phone], map: "phone_number_unique")
  @@map("user")
  UserAction UserAction[]
}

model UserAction {
  id           String @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  userId       String @map("user_id") @db.Uuid
  method       String @db.VarChar(120)
  url          String @db.VarChar(120)
  userAgent    String @db.VarChar(120)
  requestBody  Json?
  responseBody Json?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
}
```

It is supposed to be one-to-many connection, but I have this warning in terminal when trigger function that creates record:

```js
async createRecord({userId, method, url, userAgent, requestBody, responseBody}) {
    return this.prisma.userAction.create({
      data: {userId, method, url, userAgent, requestBody, responseBody}
    })
  }
```

And this warning:

```
+   user: {
+     create?: UserCreateWithoutUserActionInput | UserUncheckedCreateWithoutUserActionInput,
+     connectOrCreate?: UserCreateOrConnectWithoutUserActionInput,
+     connect?: UserWhereUniqueInput
+   },
?   id?: String,
?   updatedAt?: DateTime,
?   createdAt?: DateTime
  }
}

Argument user for data.user is missing.

Note: Lines with + are required, lines with ? are optional.
```

Actually, everything seems to be working fine, but I am wondering on how to fix this. I guess, that connection between 2 tables was created incorrect, but I have never worked with `prisma` before, so I don't really know where error is.

So, how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error because I passed an `undefined` value to a foreign key field of one of my models.

In your case, should be checked that `createRecord` is being invoked with a valid `userId`.